# lua not modifying function arguments

Tags: function, lua, arguments, binary-tree, lua-table

I've been learning lua and can't seem to make a simple implementation of this binary tree work...

```
function createTree(tree, max)
    if max > 0 then
        tree = {data = max, left = {}, right = {}}
        createTree(tree.left, max - 1)
        createTree(tree.right, max - 1)
    end
end

function printTree(tree)
    if tree then
        print(tree.data)
        printTree(tree.left)
        printTree(tree.right)
    end
end

tree = {}
createTree(tree, 3)
printTree(tree)
```

the program just returns nil after execution. I've searched around the web to understand how argument passing works in lua (if it is by reference or by value) and found out that some types are passed by reference (like tables and functions) while others by value. Still, I made the global variable "tree" a table before passing it to the "createTree" function, and I even initialized "left" and "right" to be empty tables inside of "createTree" for the same purpose. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to think that for the most of the cases lua passes arguments by value. But for any object other than a number (numbers aren't objects actually), the "value" is actually a pointer to the said object.

When you do something like `a={1,2,3}` or `b="asda"` the values on the right are allocated somewhere dynamically, and `a` and `b` only get addresses of those. Thus, when you pass `a` to the function `fun(a)`, the pointer is copied to a new variable inside function, but the `a` itself is unaffected:

```
function fun(p)
   --p stores address of the same object, but `p` is not `a`
   p[1]=3--by using the address you can 
   p[4]=1--alter the contents of the object
   p[2]=nil--this will be seen outside

   q={}
   p={}--here you assign address of another object to the pointer
   p=q--(here too)
end
```

Functions are also represented by pointers to them, you can use `debug` library to tinker with function object (change upvalues for example), this may affect how function executes, but, once again, you can not change where external references are pointing.

Strings are immutable objects, you can pass them around, there is a library that does stuff to them, but all the functions in that library return new string. So once, again external variable `b` from `b="asda"` would not be affected if you tried to do something with "asda" string inside the function.

Comment: Your answer was very clear and made me understand my mistake. Basically, my misconception was that "object" variables (such as strings and tables) were passed by REFERENCE, but I now understand that they are represented by pointers and passed by value. This makes it so that a function can change data to which they are pointing, but not the address of the pointers themselves (like when passing pointers by value to C/C++ functions, if I understood correctly). The other answers brought me close to this conclusion, but it was yours that destroyed all doubts. Thanks :)

Comment: Well explained! So basically the function arguments are constant pointers.

Answer (score 6):

It is probably necessary to initialize not by a new table, but only to set its values.

```
function createTree(tree, max)
    if max > 0 then
        tree.data = max
        tree.left = {}
        tree.right = {}
        createTree(tree.left, max - 1)
        createTree(tree.right, max - 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: While this answer brought me close to understanding the problem it was not complete. Thanks anyways providing the info necessary to circumvent my issue :)

Answer (score 5):

in Lua, arguments are passed by value. Assigning to an argument does not change the original variable.

Try this:

```
function createTree(max)
    if max == 0 then
        return nil
     else
        return {data = max, left = createTree(max-1), right = createTree(max-1)}
     end
end
```

Comment: I admit this was not the answer that made me understand my mistake, but it was still helpfull to see how you created that tree. I never thought of doing it that way; and it is even simpler and more elegant than what I came up with so thanks anyways! Still, wouldn't your version not take advantage of tail recursion?